# Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another VBSCRIPT ERROR

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

The code :

```
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>

<% 
set updatetime = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
updatetime.open "DRIVER=SQL Server;***************************************"
If request.form("in_out")="checkin" then
updatetime.execute ("insert into hourlist (username, checkintime, paid,breakCount) values ('"&session("MM_username")&"', '"&Now()&"', 0, 2) ")

End if

If request.form("in_out")="checkout" then
updatetime.execute ("update hourlist set checkouttime='"&Now()&"' where username='"&session("MM_username")&"' and checkouttime is NULL")
End if
If request.form("in_out")="breakcheckin" then
updatetime.execute ("update  hourlist set  breakCheckIn='"&Now()&"' where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"'  ")
updatetime.execute ("update  hourlist set  breakCheckOut=Null where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"' and breakCheckOut is not NULL  ") 
End if
If request.form("in_out")="breakcheckout" then
updatetime.execute ("select  breakCheckIn from hourlist where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"'  ")
Dim BTD
BTD=Round(Csng(DateDiff("n", (updatetime.Fields.Item("breakCheckIn").Value), (Now()))), 2)
updatetime.execute ("update hourlist set breakCheckOut='"&Now()&"', breakCount=breakCount-1 where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"' ")
updatetime.execute ("update hourlist set breakTime='"&BTD&"' where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"' ")
updatetime.execute ("update hourlist set breakCheckIn=NULL where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"' and breakCheckIn is not NULL ")
End if
updatetime.close
set updatetime=nothing
response.redirect "employee.asp?in_out="&request.form("in_out")

%>
```

Depending on the radio select i do diffrent things,i'm getting "ADODB.Connection error '800a0bb9' " error at 21 line(BTD=Round... line) can someone tell me what i did wrong at that line ? Did i write "updatetime.Fileds" wrong or what?

Sry for my Bad English.

Comment: Try using the ADODB.Command object to execute your SQL queries. http://www.w3schools.com/asp/ado_ref_command.asp  http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_comm_execute.asp

Comment: Is there a way to use Connection and get needed field whit it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Dim myConnection, myRecordset    
set myRecordset = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set myConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
myConnection.Open "DRIVER=SQL Server;***************************************"

myRecordset.Open "select breakCheckIn from hourlist where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"' ", myConnection

Dim bciValue = myRecordset("breakCheckIn")
Response.Write "BreakCheckIn value is: " & bciValue

myRecordset.Close
myConnection.Close
```

Comment: First you missed the `Set`, now you use () when calling a Sub.

Answer (score 0):

Your `updatetime` is a Connection, not a Recordset (with .Fields). You may need to store the result/recordset from

`updatetime.execute ("select  breakCheckIn from hourlist where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"'  ")`

in a variable and use its field(s) in the later statement(s) (or - much better - parametrized queries).

Update wrt comment:

Use `Set` to assign an object (recordset) to a variable.

Comment: `Dim BCI

Dim BTD

BCI=updatetime.execute ("select  breakCheckIn from hourlist where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"'  ")
BTD=Round(Csng(DateDiff("n", 

(BCI.Fields.Item("breakCheckIn").Value), (Now()))), 2)`

Still not working...Do i need to make Recordset or can i use Connection to get needed Field from DB?

Comment: Ty
`Dim BTD
Set BCI=updatetime.execute ("select  breakCheckIn from hourlist where ID='"&session("MM_ID")&"'  ")
BTD=Round(Csng(DateDiff("n", (BCI.Fields.Item("breakCheckIn").Value), (Now()))), 2)`
 

is the answer . :)